# Display database table with swing (Columns names do not show up)

Tags: java, database, swing

I am trying to show the data I have in my database with Swing in a Frame. 
It works but It doesn't show the columns names! just the data in the table.
This is the code I used.

```
try {
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL , USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY_FIND_ITEMS);

        {
    ResultSetMetaData md = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();

    //  Get column names
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        columnNames.add( md.getColumnName(i) );
    }

    //  Get row data
    while (rs.next())
    {
        ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
        }

        data.add( row );
    }
}
}   
catch (SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
}

Vector<String> columnNamesVector = new Vector();
Vector dataVector = new Vector();

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
    Vector subVector = new Vector();

    for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
    {
        subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
    }
    dataVector.add(subVector);
}

for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ ) {
    columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));
}
//  Create table with database data    
JTable table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)
{
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {

        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null)
            {
                return o.getClass();
            }
        }


        return Object.class;
    }
};


          JScrollPane scrollPane =new JScrollPane(table);
            getContentPane().add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST );

            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

            table.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

Why doesn't it display the columns names?

Comment: @Sanjeev : String QUERY_FIND_ITEMS = "SELECT * FROM itemsunit ";

Comment: i'm not entirely sure about it but have u tried using a tableModel to set data to the table instead?

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100 no, but my problem is not in the data , because they are all displayed correctly. 
What is missing are the names of the columns

Comment: 1- Don't override `getColumnClass` from `JTable`, use a `TableModel`, that's it's job; 2- Wrap the `JTable` to a `JScrollPane`, see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer The columns' names are still not displayed (only the data)

Comment: `catch (SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() ); }` The code after the end of the `catch` block will not work correctly if the DB query fails. Best to include that code within the `try` block. And a tip: change `System.out.println( e.getMessage() );` to `e.printStackTrace();` both shorter ***&*** more informative.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Perfect! It solved my problem 
Can you post it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: *"Can you post it as an answer.."* The site won't allow anyone to post an answer on a question that has been closed, so I posted it in answer to the one that is not closed (and included the code snippet for context).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I understand. Thank you